# how to convert string to array Before '=' as key and after '=' as value in php array

Tags: php

i have 'refrence_no=612,app_type=1,applicant_name=erf,mobile=9685362536,file_body=sdfsdf,app_from=5,created_at=2019-09-16,created_atTo=2019-09-10' this type of string i want to convert in array.

Before '=' as key and after '=' as value in php array

Comment: It's easy. Hints: Use explode. You can figure it out now.

Comment: i want this type array

[
     refrence_no=>612,
     app_type=>1
]

using only explode it is possible

Comment: Try [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function .

Comment: explode given the output is like


Array ( [0] => refrence_no=612 [1] => app_type=1 [2] => applicant_name=erf [3] => mobile=9685362536 [4] => file_body=sdfsdf [5] => app_from=5 [6] => created_at=2019-09-16 [7] => created_atTo=2019-09-10 )

Comment: Great. you are almost there. Now, make a new empty array, say `$result` and just `foreach` over this exploded array and do an explode on each element. In the explode of each element, first location is key and second location is value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "refrence_no=612,app_type=1,applicant_name=erf,mobile=9685362536,file_body=sdfsdf,app_from=5,created_at=2019-09-16,created_atTo=2019-09-10";
$array = explode(",",$str);
$newarray = [];
foreach($array as $item){
    $temp = explode("=",$item);
    $newarray[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
print_r($newarray);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [refrence_no] => 612
    [app_type] => 1
    [applicant_name] => erf
    [mobile] => 9685362536
    [file_body] => sdfsdf
    [app_from] => 5
    [created_at] => 2019-09-16
    [created_atTo] => 2019-09-10
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use explode function with foreach loop.
I have shared a example below please check it out  :

```
$string = 'refrence_no=612,app_type=1,applicant_name=erf,mobile=9685362536,file_body=sdfsdf,app_from=5,created_at=2019-09-16,created_atTo=2019-09-10';

$new_array= explode(',',$string );
       foreach ($new_array as $data){
           $explode_value= explode('=',$data);
           $final_value[$explode_value[0]] = $explode_value[1];
       }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($final_value);die('mms');
output will be :
Array
(
    [refrence_no] => 612
    [app_type] => 1
    [applicant_name] => erf
    [mobile] => 9685362536
    [file_body] => sdfsdf
    [app_from] => 5
    [created_at] => 2019-09-16
    [created_atTo] => 2019-09-10
)
```